# ngx-owl-carousel-o options autoplay true not working?

Tags: angular, owl-carousel

I need help how this autoplay true get it working. I have write this issue because I couldn't find the same as mine. I really need your eyes to see something that have missed or missed up. Thanks in advance y'all.

> review-section.component.html

```
<div class="section section-review">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container custom">
            <owl-carousel-o [options]="carouselOptions">
                <ng-template carouselSlide>
                    <img src="./assets/img/faces/joe-gardner-2.jpg">
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template carouselSlide>
                    <img src="./assets/img/faces/joe-gardner-2.jpg">
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template carouselSlide>
                    <img src="./assets/img/faces/joe-gardner-2.jpg">
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template carouselSlide>
                    <img src="./assets/img/faces/joe-gardner-2.jpg">
                </ng-template>
            </owl-carousel-o>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> review-section.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OwlOptions } from 'ngx-owl-carousel-o';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-review-section',
  templateUrl: './review-section.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./review-section.component.css']
})
export class ReviewSectionComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  carouselOptions: OwlOptions = {
    nav: false,
    loop: true,
    mouseDrag: true,
    touchDrag: true,
    pullDrag: true,
    dots: false,
    autoplay: true,
    navSpeed: 700,
    navText: ['', ''],
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1
      },
      400: {
        items: 2
      },
      740: {
        items: 3
      },
      940: {
        items: 4
      }
    },
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

> angular.json

```
"styles": [
   "node_modules/ngx-owl-carousel-o/lib/styles/prebuilt-themes/owl.carousel.min.css",
   "node_modules/ngx-owl-carousel-o/lib/styles/prebuilt-themes/owl.theme.default.min.css"
],
```

> src/styles.scss

```
@import '../node_modules/ngx-owl-carousel-o/lib/styles/scss/owl.carousel.scss';
@import '../node_modules/ngx-owl-carousel-o/lib/styles/scss/owl.theme.default.scss';
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by installing ngx-owl-carousel-o Dependency

> npm i tslib

[image]

Comment: This did'nt do the trick for me :c

Answer (score -1):

try this....

```
<ng-template carouselSlide class="item">
   <img src="./assets/img/faces/joe-gardner-2.jpg">
 </ng-template>
```

.....over each ng-template

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).